# Spring @Async or EJB @Asynchronous for asynchronous service invocation ?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb

I am working on a project using Hibernate JPA and Spring MVC, I am looking into implementing an asynchronous service, and I realized that I am getting the two annotations @Async or @Asynchronous from repectively Spring and EJB.

Everything here is pretty new for me, and I would go for the EJB @Asynchronous and see how it goes, I was wondering if one solution has an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@Async`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) and [`@Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) are identical in their capabilities. They both run given method in a separate thread pool and they both allow `void` and `Future<T>` result type. There is no functional different between them. The only (minor) advantage of Spring is that you have full control over underlying thread pool while with `@Asynchronous` this is probably configured on a container-specific basis.

If your application already uses Spring MVC, `@Async` seems like a natural consequence.